# Is it possible to recompose only once when navigating using `navController` on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm new to Android Jetpack Compose and I wanted to validate the navigation process before applying on a large app.

I've been testing using `@Preview` and running it on both TV emulators and actual devices and I wrote two versions of the UI: one using a simple variable to navigate manually to destinations and another one using `NavHost`.

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.compose.tv"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.6"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {

    val composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01")
    implementation(composeBom)

    // General compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")

    // Compose for TV dependencies
    val tvCompose = "1.0.0-alpha10"
    implementation("androidx.tv:tv-foundation:$tvCompose")
    implementation("androidx.tv:tv-material:$tvCompose")
}
```

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

Manual navigation which recomposes as I expected, only once:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ManualNav() {
    var selectedScreen by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    // buttons representing menu items 
    Column(Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = { selectedScreen = 0 }) {
            Text(text = "Button 1")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Button(onClick = { selectedScreen = 1 }) {
            Text(text = "Button 2")
        }
    }

    // hypothetical content of each screen
    Box(Modifier.padding(150.dp)) {
        when (selectedScreen) {
            0 -> {
                SideEffect {
                    println("recomposed screen 1")
                }
                Button(
                    onClick = {},
                    colors = ButtonDefaults
                        .colors(containerColor = Color.Red)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Content 1")
                }
            }

            1 -> {
                SideEffect {
                    println("recomposed screen 2")
                }
                Button(
                    onClick = {},
                    colors = ButtonDefaults
                        .colors(containerColor = Color.Blue)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Content 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result when clicking on each menu button (starting from the second one since the first loads as the default during startup):

```
recomposed screen 2
recomposed screen 1
```

Now the same logic using `NavHost`

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun NavHostPreview() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val navigate: (route: String) -> Unit = { route ->
        navController.navigate(route)
    }

    Column(Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = { navigate("screen1") }) {
            Text(text = "Button 1")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Button(onClick = { navigate("screen2") }) {
            Text(text = "Button 2")
        }
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "root",
        enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
        exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
        popEnterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
        popExitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }
    ) {
        navigation(startDestination = "screen1", route = "root") {
            composable("screen1") {
                SideEffect {
                    println("recomposed screen 1")
                }
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(150.dp),
                    onClick = {},
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.colors(containerColor = Color.Red)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Content 1")
                }
            }
            composable("screen2") {
                SideEffect {
                    println("recomposed screen 2")
                }
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(150.dp),
                    onClick = {},
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.colors(containerColor = Color.Blue)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Content 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

Clicking first on button 2

```
recomposed screen 1
recomposed screen 2
recomposed screen 2
recomposed screen 2
```

Button 1:

```
recomposed screen 2
recomposed screen 1
recomposed screen 1
recomposed screen 1
```

Why is the `NavHost` version recomposing 3 times the destination and even itself once? What am I missing here? I've tried several combinations and possibilities with this but there is always more than one recomposition of the destination.

Comment: Exactly Same thing , I wasted my 2 weeks thinking my code was wrong at last i understood it happened because of navcontroller shi** google no answer yet